# Flattening a DataMatrix of DataMatrices

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics, data-manipulation

I am obtaining microarray data from NCBI using the `getgeodata()` method.  This returns a *struct*, with a field **Data**, which is a *DataMatrix* with each column representing a different sample and rows representing the probes.  For some reason though, each cell in the DataMatrix is itself a 1x1 DataMatrix and so, when I try to do something like:

```
am_accession = getgeodata('GSE2034')
am_data_adj = rmabackadj(am_accession.Data)
```

Matlab throws the error:

> Error using rmabackadj (line 80)
>   Probe intensity values must be numeric and
>   real.

I suppose I need to flatten the DataMatrix so that the values in the 1x1 DataMatrices are the values in the larger DataMatrix, however, I'm unsure how to accomplish this in Matlab.

Any idea how to do this (idiomatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataMatrix appears to be a matlab class  / object (specifically  `bioma.data.DataMatrix`).

Which means you can read its documentation, i.e. `doc bioma.data.DataMatrix`.
You can also get a list of available methods directly from the object, by pressing `[TAB]` after writing the name of the DataMatrix and a dot in your console.

In any case, there seems to be a `.double()` method which does exactly what you want, i.e. convert all the data into an array of doubles, i.e.

```
am_accesion.Data.double()
```

Comment: It's an interesting data structure; I have not come accross it. You can do things like `MyData(:,'columnname')`, or `MyData([1:5],{'columnname1','columnname2'})`. That's pretty cool; nice to know this exists.

Comment: seems similar to an R data.frame. The DataMatrix in a DataMatrix is just weird though, even if it is stored like that - it makes the variable inspection view useless.

Comment: It makes sense if you want to obtain a subset where you still retain the ability to query by row/columnnames (i.e. it's a subset of the same type). The real weakness is matlab's inability to chain operators, so you have to assign temporary variables all-over the place, i.e. do `d = Data(1:10,1:10); d.double()` rather than `Data(1:10,1:10).double()` or even `Data.double()(1:10,1:10)`